# using __FUNCTION__ within macro

Tags: visual-c++

I need to have function name. I have done two procedures to print it's name:
Using macro:

```
define LogFnc(info) do {cout<<"=FUNCTION= "<info ; } while(0)
```

and using function:

```
void LogFnc(string info)
{
    cout<<"=FUNCTION= "<<info;
}
```

Procedure that calls one of those possibilities:

```
int main() {
    LogFnc(__FUNCTION__);
}
```

Why in case I use macro (firs one) no function name is printed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you forgot one bracket in cout<<"=FUNCTION= " **<<** info

```
#define LogFnc(info) cout<<"=FUNCTION= " << info ;
```

Let me say moreover that your false loop `do{...}while(0)` is ugly, non intuitive, and counter-productive.

Comment: On the contrary, the `do { ... } while (0)` is exceptionally common in macros, because it allows you to use them more like functions.

Comment: @DietrichEpp , I'm interested, but I don't see the added value of that construction, could you elaborate a bit ?